# How to make a subdomain record point to a subfolder of my website "godaddy domain manager"?

Tags: domain, subdomain, godaddy, directory

I have a dedicated server on a webhosting company "not godaddy", and I manage my domains through godaddy.
I want to add a new subdomain and want this domain to point to a certain folder in my website.
I tried to add a new record : mysubdomain -> www.mywebsite.com/subfolder  but godaddy appeared a message that this is not a right formate.
How to do this?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In website hosting context, DNS only maps domain names to server addresses with A (or AAAA) records. Basically that is like telling the system "I want this domain to be hosted by *that* hoster.".

Everything beyond this is done by your hoster. When you open `domain.com` or `sub.domain.com` in a browser, the connection can be done to the same server, but different content will be presented, as the webserver can distinguish between these two cases.

Without further information about your hoster this question cannot be answered.

Comment: You are right, and I asked another question for this there: http://serverfault.com/questions/206999/how-to-make-a-subdomain-point-to-a-page-in-iis7

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS, you will want to check out the web.config settings or for Apache .htaccess settings. You can test this out from a windows machine by modifying C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts and adding the IP address to test it as this is much quicker than waiting the hour for the IP address to be changed on the different servers and finally reach you. Not sure how to do it on Mac or Linux though...